# Unsure of Client Server IP configuration in Java

Tags: java, configuration, client, ip

I have a written a simple Client-Server pair, sending an Object to the server. I have tested the code and it works, provided I use LOCALHOST as the server name.

When attempting to connect to the server using my own IP address, the client continuously times out. I cannot help thinking I've missed a trick, if someone could take a look at the code I would be very grateful. Many Thanks, J.

client

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
  ObjectInputStream ois = null;
  Socket socket = null;
  Person p = null;

  try {
    // My IP address entered here..
    socket = new Socket("xx.xx.xxx.xxx", 3000);
    // open I/O streams for objects
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


    /*
    // read an object from the server
    p = (Person) ois.readObject();
    System.out.print("Name is: " + p.getName());
    oos.close();
    ois.close();*/

    //write object to the server
   // p = new Person("HAL");
    oos.writeObject(new Person("HAL"));
    oos.flush();
    ois.close();
    oos.close();

  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

Server

```
public Server() throws Exception {
 server = new ServerSocket(3000);
 System.out.println("Server listening on port 3000.");
 this.start();
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to make your server bind to `0.0.0.0` (wildcard, all interfaces on your machine) or the specific IP you want it to listen on. The `ServerSocket` constructor you're using only takes a port number and binds to `localhost` which is going to resolve to `127.0.0.1`

```
server = new ServerSocket(3000, 5, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
```

**Edit to add:** The second paramater is the *backlog* size. This is the number of connections that can be queued waiting for you to `accept()` them before additional connection attempts will result in "connection refused".

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the response its helped me to understand the process. However, the connection is still timing out when using the above server constructor. I have even tried to set the InetAddress to my IP, but gave me a Bind Exception on compiling.

Comment: Are you doing this on your home computer that's behind a router? The above code works perfectly on my machine. If you can post the stack trace I can maybe help.

Comment: Yes. I have turned off the firewall on the machine I'm working on. Its quite strange, I've attempted about 12 times since last replying. And it has worked just the once.

Comment: Your machine has a private IP address (probably in the 192.168.0.0 space). That's what it's going to bind to with `0.0.0.0`. You can't bind to your public IP address because your machine doesn't have that; your router does. If you want to connect via your public IP address you have to configure your router to forward port 3000 to your machine's private IP.

Comment: Yes, the time it was successful the server accepted a connection from 192.168.1.1.  So, if I am understanding you correctly, the reason my machine cannot connect to the server is because the server has no access to the public ip, only the router does. And when a packet comes to the router via this public IP, the router then sends it to the server address (a "random" ip). So effectively my packet is send to the router and then lost?

Comment: Requests to port 3000 sent to your public IP (your router) should just be refused or hang (depends on the router) unless the router is configured to forward connections to that port to somewhere else.

Comment: Cool, so effectively I should reconfigure the router to forward all messages to port 3000 to the IP specified in the server? (in this case 0.0.0.0) I have little network background so please excuse if I seem quite slow on the pickup, I dont want to miss a trick.

Comment: No, you have to have the router forward port 3000 to *your machine's IP address* on your private network. The `0.0.0.0`is not a real address; it's a wildcard (`INADDR_ANY` in the underlying system libraries) that tells the socket library to bind to all available IP addresses on your machine.

Comment: Ok thats cool,do you know how I can find the address my machine has been given by the network?

Comment: Depends on your OS. In windows you have to go to the network connection and look at the details. On *nix systems (incl. OSX) it's the `ifconfig` command to list your interfaces.